# What Salats/prayers are Bid'ahs/innovations?

Tags: salat, bidah

As is fact, there is a lot of Bid'ahs (بدع)/innovations today.  And there are Salawats/prayers that are also innovations, and it is important to know which salat is innovation so you do not fall into an innovation. An example of a Salat that is an innovation in the religion, is Salatul Tasbeeh, it is an Innovation because the Hadith in which it is found in is Fabricated.  So my question is what other Salawat are innovations? and what is the reason they are an innovation?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following Salat to be Biddah, some of them even reach the point of Shirk:

- [Salaat al-raghaa’ib](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/60180) done in the month of Rajab.
- [Salat Ghausiya](http://drabutamim.blogspot.in/2011/05/lessons-in-shirk-salat-al-ghauthiyya.html) (done by the sufi sects like Barelvis, is very popular in Indo Subcontinent) in commemoration of Abdul Kadir Jeelani (named as Ghausul Azam)

After completion of this special prayer the person is supposed to supplicate to Shaykh 'Abdil Qadir Gilani in the following words moving towards the direction of the tomb of Shaikh Abdul Qadir Jelani in Baghdad:

> Ya Ghaus Saqalaini Ya Kareem-at-Tarfaini Aghisni was amdidni fi
>   Qada-e-Hajati Ya Qaadi al Hajaat

Thus this particular Salat is clear Shirk yet is very common among the people of the Indo Subcontinent.

- [Salatul Tasbeeh](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/145112) may be a Bidah due to a weak hadith and not fabricated hadith.
- [Specially crafted Salats](http://hibamagazine.com/innovations-in-the-month-of-shaban/) with particular number and names of Surahs during the Night of Shaban

Comment: salatul tara'veeh is the most common bidaa'h